# Making micropayments possible

Tags: exchanges, payments, iot

I think it's clear that the current ethereum network is not quite suitable for IoT based micro payments. And the slow transition toward PoS, which recently started, will put even more emphasis on gas payment as a reward for mining, hence (correct me if I'm wrong) not enabling an ecosystem for high frequency affordable micro payment system in a foreseeable future.

Are there any development of an alternative on in the ethereum world? Or outside of it?

Answer (score 2):

There a few projects working on micro payments:

- Raiden Network https://raiden.network/101.html - analogous to lightning network for Bitcoin
- Micro Raiden https://raiden.network/micro.html - Micropayments for Ethereum
- Machinomy https://machinomy.com/ - micropayments in Ether and ERC20 tokens over HTTP

Comment: Thanks, and would you be able to roughly explain how those low fees, quick confirmations could be done, given it still runs on main network?

Comment: You can create a payment channel between 2 parties by creating a contract on the main network depositing some Ether/ERC20 tokens. After that the parties can make payments to each other by exchanging cryptographically signed messages off-chain. This mechanism is designed in such a way that both parties are guaranteed to get their payments on the main net without submitting any transactions. The payment channel has to be closed at the end by submitting another transaction to the main net. The channels can be combined into a network enabling payments involving more than 2 parties.

Comment: Because the messages are exchanged off-chain you don't need to pay fees and wait for block confirmations.